# Apply Css style into webkit-slider-thumb

Tags: javascript, html, css, input-type-range

I would like it to be like [this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Wfurm.png)

**HTML:**

```
  &ltdiv id="container">
&ltdiv id="volume">
      &lti class="fa fa-volume-up" aria-hidden="true" id="vol-h"></i>
                        &lti class="fa fa-volume-off" aria-hidden="true" id="vol-m"></i>
      &ltdiv id="vol">&ltdiv id="go">&lt/div>&lt/div>
&lt/div>
&lt/div>
```

**CSS:**

```
#container {
  top:   810px;
  flex-flow: row wrap;
  align-items: center;
  padding: 1px 3px;
  display: flex;
  position: absolute;
  border: none;
  width: 100%;
  height: auto;
}
#container::before{
  z-index: -1;
  content: ' ';
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  position: fixed;
  bottom: -850px;
  background: url(../images/NY.png);
  background-size:cover;
  -webkit-filter: blur(8px);
  filter: blur(25px);
}
#container #volume {
  width: 90px;
  position: relative;
  top: 50px;
  left: 1600px;
  cursor: pointer;
}
#container #volume .fa-volume-up {
  font-size: 1em;
  color: #019875;
  -webkit-filter: drop-shadow(0px 2px 2px #000);
  filter: drop-shadow(0px 2px 2px #000);
  position: relative;
}
#container #volume .fa-volume-off {
  font-size: 1em;
  color: #019875;
  -webkit-filter: drop-shadow(0px 2px 2px #000);
  filter: drop-shadow(0px 2px 2px #000);
  position: relative;
}
#container #volume .fa-volume-up:hover {
  color: #4C4C4C;
}
#container #volume #vol {
  opacity: 0;
  -webkit-animation: fadeOutUp ease-in 1;
  -moz-animation: fadeOutUp ease-in 1;
  animation: fadeOutUp ease-in 1;
  -webkit-animation-fill-mode: forwards;
  -moz-animation-fill-mode: forwards;
  animation-fill-mode: forwards;
  -webkit-animation-duration: 0.4s;
  -moz-animation-duration: 0.4s;
  animation-duration: 0.4s;
  width: 23px;
  height: 130px;
  background: #141414;
  position: absolute;
  top: -160px;
  left: -2px;
  -webkit-border-radius: 2px;
  -moz-border-radius: 2px;
  -ms-border-radius: 2px;
  border-radius: 2px;
  padding: 10px 10px;
  -webkit-box-shadow: 0px 0px 1px 1px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.5);
  -moz-box-shadow: 0px 0px 1px 1px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.5);
  box-shadow: 0px 0px 1px 1px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.5);
}
#container #volume #vol::before {
  content: "";
  width: 10px;
  height: 10px;
  position: absolute;
  bottom: -5px;
  left: 6px;
  background-color: #141414;
  -ms-transform: rotate(45deg);
  -webkit-transform: rotate(45deg);
  transform: rotate(45deg);
}
#container #volume #vol.active {
  -webkit-animation: fadeInDown ease-in 1;
  -moz-animation: fadeInDown ease-in 1;
  animation: fadeInDown ease-in 1;
  -webkit-animation-fill-mode: forwards;
  -moz-animation-fill-mode: forwards;
  animation-fill-mode: forwards;
  -webkit-animation-duration: 0.4s;
  -moz-animation-duration: 0.4s;
  animation-duration: 0.4s;
}
#container #volume #vol #go {
  width: 3px;
  height: 100%;
  background: #019875;
  /* Old browsers */
  background: -moz-linear-gradient(45deg, #019875 0%, #003023 50%, #019875 100%);
  /* FF3.6-15 */
  background: -webkit-linear-gradient(45deg, #019875 0%, #003023 50%, #019875 100%);
  /* Chrome10-25,Safari5.1-6 */
  background: linear-gradient(45deg, #019875 0%, #003023 50%, #019875 100%);
  /* W3C, IE10+, FF16+, Chrome26+, Opera12+, Safari7+ */
  -webkit-border-radius: 5px;
  -moz-border-radius: 5px;
  -ms-border-radius: 5px;
  border-radius: 5px;
  position: relative;
}
#container #volume #vol #go::before {
  content: "";
  width: 100%;
  height: 22px;
  background-color: #4C4C4C;
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  -webkit-border-radius: 5px;
  -moz-border-radius: 5px;
  -ms-border-radius: 5px;
  border-radius: 5px;
}
#container #volume #vol #go::after {
  content: "";
  width: 9px;
  height: 9px;
  background-color: #019875;
  position: absolute;
  top: 75px;
  left: -3px;
  -webkit-border-radius: 50px;
  -moz-border-radius: 50px;
  -ms-border-radius: 50px;
  border-radius: 50px;
  -webkit-box-shadow: 0px 0px 2px 2px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.5);
  -moz-box-shadow: 0px 0px 2px 2px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.5);
  box-shadow: 0px 0px 2px 2px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.5);
}
```

**JavaScipt:**

```
$( "#volume" ).click(function() {
  $( "#vol" ).toggleClass( "active" );
});
```

Here is a [link](http://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.5/css/bootstrap.min.css) to the included icon Bootstrap.
I tried applying the styling to the webkit but didn't work. Any suggestions on how to apply that style to it ?